# 'NoneType' object is not callable for an object that has a value?

Tags: python, python-2.7, nonetype

I have the following two lines of code:

```
print(test)
print(test.type())
```

There is something being printed out by the code, namely the value of `test`.  However, when I check the type of test through `test.type()`, i get the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable`.  How is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`test.type` is None.

Use `type(test)` instead.